# Any third library to draw a Half Pie Chart (Semi Circle) with Animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, charts, pie-chart

Anybody knows any third library with permission granted for using it? I need to draw a Half Pie Chart like this, with an animation applied.

I want to get something like this:

[image]

This is what you get with [HUChart](https://github.com/hugo53/HUChart) but it is drawn without an Animation at all.

I found others libraries which let you draw the Pie Chart animated, but not the Half part of the Chart.

https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart

https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it applying some changes to the example project of [MagicPie](https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/MagicPie)

Its a third library that works with `Core Animation`.

Changing the properties '`startAngle`' and '`endAngle`' of the the property '`PieLayer`' in the `UIView` where the Pies are drawn.

```
self.layer.startAngle = 0;
self.layer.endAngle = 180;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use third party control- [HUChart](https://github.com/hugo53/HUChart)

You may change code for draw with animation. Hope this will help you